# Rendering HTML code as text

Tags: html

I have to make a an HTML tutorial. I need to show in the page html code examples. So, I want to have code displayed like this:

```
 <h1>hi</h1>
```

not like this

## hi

Is there any tag to do this? Or how can I do this only with HTML?

Comment: Do you mean the `<pre>` and `<code>` elements? Normally you'd also use `&lt;` and `&gt;` for the `<` and `>` within those tags.

Comment: You can do it with encoding tags: `&lt;h1&gt;hi&lt;/h1&gt;`

Answer (score 3):

You can encode characters to get them to show on a live page. For tags, use `&lt;` to make a < and `&gt;` to make >.

```html
<h1>&lt;h1&gt;text&lt;/h1&gt;</h1>
```

You can see more ways to change various characters when you write HTML at the link below.
http://www.escapecodes.info/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the idea!